# How to transform an array of objects with the same property name into the object in which value is concatenated from values in a given array? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array of objects which looks like this:

```
const arr = [
  {integer: "3"},
  {integer: "500"}
]
```

As a result i want to get the object that looks like this: `mergedObj = {digits: "3500"}`

I tried to use reduce, but it seems that i'm doing something wrong.
Here is my code:

```
var mergedObj = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {

   acc["digits"] = [acc[obj.integer]].concat(obj.integer).join("");

    return acc;
}, {});
```

Here is the result of what i'm getting:

```
"Object is", [object Object] {
  digits: "500"
}
```

The problem is that i'm missing the first part of my digit. Please help me! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got this. The `[acc[obj.integer]]` part should be `[acc.digits]`. Anyway, you can do it much simpler:

```js
const arr = [
  {integer: "3"},
  {integer: "500"}
]

var mergedObj = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {

   acc.digits += obj.integer;

    return acc;
}, { digits: '' });

console.log(mergedObj);
```

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Why don't you initialise `acc`  as `{digits: ""}` and adjust callback code appropriately? I hope it will reduce your code a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.map()` to create an array of `integer`, and then join. Assign to `digits` property of a new object:

```js
const arr = [
  {integer: "3"},
  {integer: "500"}
]

const result = {
  digits: arr.map(o => o.integer).join('')
};

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
const arr = [
   {integer: "3"},
   {integer: "500"}
]

let output = {'digits':''};
arr.map(function (item) {
    output['digits'] += item['integer']
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: It's an abuse of `.map()`. `.map()` is there to change elements of the array and return a new one. It's not designed for simple iteration.